# How to do dynamic reverse string interpolation

Tags: javascript, regex, interpolation

Here's a test I'm writing for some code:

```
    const transclude = '{fieldA}-{fieldB}-{fieldC}';
    const val = {
      fieldA: 'one',
      fieldB: 'two',
      fieldC: 'three',
    };
    const expected = 'one-two-three';
```

Should be straight forward, given the object, I want to interpolate those values into the `transclude` string and get the result.

Now here's a neat thing I was thinking of, is it possible to go backwards?

```
    const transclude = '{fieldA}-{fieldB}-{fieldC}';
    const val = 'one-two-three';
    const expected = {
      fieldA: 'one',
      fieldB: 'two',
      fieldC: 'three',
    };
```

Just to weed out the bad answers from the good, the following would need to work as well:

```
    const transclude = '{fieldA}-{fieldB}-some-value-{fieldC}';
    const val = 'one-two-some-value-three';
    const expected = {
      fieldA: 'one',
      fieldB: 'two',
      fieldC: 'three',
    };
```

EDIT: Gotta say, I'm not sure why I got a close vote on this question - it seems to me like I have a very clear problem I'm trying to solve? If the voter thinks I need more focus, please comment and let me know how to improve the question.

Comment: You need to show your attempt..  What have you tried?  and if you run into a specific problem, post your specific question, but you can't expect anyone to just do your coding for you. I'm sure you know this. :)

Comment: FWIW I don't think it should be closed, and I'm not the DV, but it *does* seem to me to be the kind of thing a 33k rep user/JS gold badge holder could handle with a little judicious  googling (and by that I mean click 3 links, tops)...

Comment: @BryanElliott - I have NO IDEA where to begin reverse string interpolation (admittedly I may be over thinking what I'm actually trying to do, happens to me a lot). "but you can't expect anyone to just do your coding for you" I'm not an "I didn't try anything" kind of question asker, I figured my rep would indicate that, pretty harsh.

Comment: I think the `val` in your third example is wrong. Shouldn't it be `one-two-some-value-three`?

Comment: Hint: [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) given the right regular expression pops out matches.

Comment: @fubar - yep, thanks for that.

Comment: You basically need to turn `transclude` into a regular expression with capture groups where you have `{xxx}`. If you use named capture groups, it will pipe out the `expected` result.

Comment: E.g. `{fieldA}` becomes `(?P<fieldA>.*)`

Comment: @Barmar - thanks, that put me on the right track. Some nights I have "off" nights where my brain is tired. People on SO are crazy harsh. I'm not trying to be a wimp, but 33k, holy cow, tough crowd. Mind turning that hint into an answer and I'll accept?

Comment: @Adam, apologies, didn't mean to come across harsh. Jared Smith, yes good point. Agreed. My apologies.

Comment: @Snow gimme codez? Seriously? Now I get all the meta stuff that's been going around about a harsh SO community. I can understand this happening to a user with 100 or 200 rep. I'm not trying to flaunt myself or anything, but I've given to this community significantly, and these are the kind of comments that are made on a genuine question that I was struggling with?

Comment: @JaredSmith What would you google to solve this problem? It's not exactly a common operation. I think you were a bit harsh.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I wasn't specific enough with my italics. "It *seems* (emphasis changed) like the kind of problem that a 33k rep user/JS gold badge holder..." etc etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your `transclude` string into a regular expression with named capture groups. The `groups` property of the result of the match will contain the desired object.

```js
const transclude = '{fieldA}-{fieldB}-some-value-{fieldC}';
const transRE = new RegExp(transclude.replace(/\{(.*?)\}/g, '(?<$1>.*)'));
const val = 'one-two-some-value-three';
const result = val.match(transRE);
console.log(result.groups);
```

Note that this won't always produce the same results as the original data, as there can be ambiguities. E.g.

```
    const transclude = '{fieldA}-{fieldB}-{fieldC}';
    const val = {
      fieldA: 'one',
      fieldB: 'two-five',
      fieldC: 'three',
    };
```

will produce `one-two-five-three`, but the reverse will produce

```
result = {
    fieldA: 'one-two',
    fieldB: 'five',
    fieldC: 'three'
}
```

because `.*` is greedy.

Comment: Trickier to dynamically generate the regexp, I'm not a great regexer, but I'll certainly give it a shot rather than ask for any more help on here based on the original feedback I've gotten to this question. Maybe that's the hard part that all the commenters above thought was so easy - I need to dynamically generate the regexp?

Comment: It's another regular expression. Replace `{(.*?)}` with `(?<$1>.*)`

Comment: looking at this answer (from an obviously extremely intelligent and respected user) - how is it not ridiculously obvious to all the commenters how easy this solution was? *sarcasm*

Comment: I don't think any of the commenters were suggesting that it would be easy. But there was no evidence that you even tried, which is what we expect, and a high rep user should know that.

Comment: And since you said that doing the interpolation was straightforward, they thought you should be able to give some thought to how to do this.

Comment: "...could handle with a little judicious googling" - still haven't found this very great answer through googling. Maybe I'm not smart enough to use the correct search terms

Comment: That does seem a bit disingenous to me, I'm not sure what I would search for to solve this. It just seemed obvious to me that your transclude is just a pattern to match, and pattern = regular expression.

Comment: BTW, I had to use google to find out how to use `.groups` to get the matches.